# Listing column values using SQL Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm learning databases and I have a question:

How can i list all the TV serial numbers that have been viewed?

My table is as follows:

```
TV:TVSerialNumber(PK),TVModelNumber, TVMake

ViewingTable: TvSerialNumber(FK),Comments

SELECT `TvSerialNumber`FROM `ViewingTable`
```

Am i using the correct format for finding the 'INDIVIDUAL' TV serial numbers that have been viewed?

Comment: Based on the schema description, you don't need to join anything. It appears you have a table to holds the serial numbers that have been viewed. All you should need to do is query that table as you are.

Comment: You will probably get each serial as often as there are comments stored in the `ViewingTable`. As I don't know what you intent to do or when you create entries in `ViewingTable` I can't answer you question.

Comment: I need to run a query to list all the individual TV Serial Number that has been viewed, As a TV can be viewed more than once, I need to find a way to just show the TV Serial Number once, which has been viewed.

Comment: This will give you the distinct serial number of viewed TVs: `SELECT DISTINCT TvSerialNumber FROM ViewingTable;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the distinct serial number of viewed TVs:

`SELECT DISTINCT TvSerialNumber FROM ViewingTable;`

You were close - you just needed to use 'DISTINCT'

Answer (score 0):

no

the database wont tell you what has been viewed, you have to tell it to

you *could* creade a new column on that table set it to int with a legnth of 1

0 for unviewed or 1 for viewed

Comment: I think he has a table `ViewingTable` just for this purpose. No need for anything else.